# Flutter Firebase Storage - [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created Error

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to upload a file to Firebase Storage. But I'm getting an error on the full install part.

Codes:

```
final Storage storage = Storage();

...

FloatingActionButton.large(
  child: Icon(Icons.folder, color: Colors.white, size: 45,),
  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 36, 36),
  onPressed: () async {
    final results = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
      allowMultiple: false,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', "jpeg"],
    );
    if (results == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Not selected image."),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 36, 36, 36),
        ),
      );
      return null;
    }
    final path = results.files.single.path!;
    final fileName = results.files.single.name;

    storage.uploadFile(path, fileName);
  },
),
```

`Storage` class:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class Storage {
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  Future<void> uploadFile(String filePath, String fileName) async {
    File file = File(filePath);
    try {
      await _storage.ref("$fileName").putFile(file);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

While uploading the full image I get the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:193
#1      Firebase.app
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:53
#2      FirebaseStorage.instance
package:firebase_storage/src/firebase_storage.dart:51
#3      new Storage
package:bolataktar_resimyukleme/firebase/storage_services.dart:6
#4      storage
package:bolataktar_resimyukleme/screens/resimyukleme_main.dart:11
```

`main.dart:`

```
import 'package:bolataktar_resimyukleme/screens/resimyukleme_main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import "package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart";
import 'package:firedart/firedart.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: BolatAktarApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please call this first  Firebase.initializeApp() as per error : see this doc : https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/example

Comment: @HardikMehta Already in the `main.dart` file `Firebase.initializeApp();` I did. I updated the topic.

Comment: await is missing Firebase.initializeApp(); for this

Comment: @HardikMehta I did but the problem persists.

Comment: Please clean and build again and for which platform are you checking ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem here are the changes I did in project

**In AndroidManifest.xml**

add below services in application tag

```
 </application>
...
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
           android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar"
           android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
           android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
           android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar"
           android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar"
           android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
   </service>
</application>
```

Don't forget to add permission for internet in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**In app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services" //This is new line
.....
compileSdkVersion 31
```

**In Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' //you can use updated version here.
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'//New Added with version 4.3.13 older one was not able to find by android studio.
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'//New Line
```

After this

```
flutter clean
```

close Android studio and restarted again(don't know why but closing studio works) and then.

```
flutter pub get
```

use await at firebase initialise

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

For test purpose you can change firebase storage rules like this

```
rules_version = '3';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write : if true
      // allow read, write: if request.auth != null; //Use this when your testing Done only authentic user should be able to upload
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did what you said but I still can't upload a picture. And it gives the same error.

Comment: what is the exception now or you are getting any error

Comment: I did what you said and I get this error: `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()`

Comment: did you added await before Firebase.initializeApp().